# Hydrograph in GRASS

Tags: grass-gis

How to make hydrograph for a basin in GRASS?

While surfing the GRASS home page, I came to know that some time back in GRASS 4.x a command *r.water.fee* existed. I understand, it is missing in GRASS 6.4. Is there any equivalent command for this? Any alternate?

Comment: Perhaps best asked on the GRASS GIS user list where many more people read...

Answer (score 1):

The command name is [r.water.fea](http://skagit.meas.ncsu.edu/~helena/gmslab/grassman5/html/r.water.fea.html)

You may want to check here for alternatives: http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/Hydrological_Sciences